# Unrendered content Cornerstone through REST API

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to get raw content through REST API

When I call "http://mysite.tld/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/456" I receive rendered content

```
"content": {
"rendered": "<div id=\"something\"></div>\n",
"protected": false
},
```

but I want the content to be unrendered

LE: I found something in /wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php

```
if ( ! empty( $schema['properties']['content'] ) ) {
    $data['content'] = array(
        'raw' => $post->post_content,
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        'rendered'  => post_password_required( $post ) ? '' : apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ),
        'protected' => (bool) $post->post_password,
    );
}
```

If I replace

```
'rendered'  => post_password_required( $post ) ? '' : apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ),
```

with

```
'rendered'  => $post->post_content,
```

it works well but how can I edit this from a custom plugin?
btw: i noticed "raw" is missing from api response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, as it depends on the *context*.

The raw content will show up for the `edit` but not the `view` or `embed` context.

It's filtered through the `WP_REST_Controller::filter_response_by_context()` method.

You can always add a new field to the response with [`register_rest_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/) where the `get_callback` callback receives an input array with post data, including the raw content.

But then you should watch out to not leak out e.g. password protected posts or content hidden with shortcodes.

Comment: W̶e̶l̶l̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶I̶ ̶s̶e̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶A̶P̶I̶?̶   Thanks. I figured it out

Comment: Hey! I know this post is very old but may you share the URL you used in order to get unrendered content in your JSON?

Comment: If we visit e.g. `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` then we only get rendered post content (with the `the_content` filter applied on the `post_content` field) in the view context, so we would need to add the raw database field (without applying the `the_content` filter) using  `register_rest_field()` with a plugin ( I think there are examples in the Codex). But watch out for password protected content and shortcodes. Hope that helps @user3191334.